# how to add a form with dyanamic fileds, multiple times on a page by a button click or any other interface

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have a form which contains a select box that fetches options from database. I want multiple instances of same form, if required. by a button click or any other interface. Also some suggestion on how to process the data  will receive from the orignal form and its instances which are added after wards. I am attaching a sample form to explain what I expect to do.

// html and php file

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="feild1[]" />
    <input type="text" name="feild2[]" />
    <!--  There is a select box that frtches data from databse using php sql -->

    <?php
    include 'databaseConnect.php'; // data base connection file
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT colID,columName FROM tableName");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
        ?>
        <select id="form1" name="select[]" method="POST" required >
            <?php while ($rowsResult = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rowsResult['colID']; ?>"> <?php echo $rowsResult['columName']; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```